# jquery Post , data object

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, post

I try to understand one thing.

I want to post an object with jquery Ajax POST , something like this:

```
var dataPostYear = {
    viewType:GetViewType(),
    viewDate:'2009/09/08',
    languageId:GetLanguageId()
};


 $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: url,
   data: dataPostYear,
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   dataType: "json",
   success: OnLoadYearListSuccess,
   error: OnLoadYearListError  
  });
```

and it doesn't work.

But this one works fine:

```
var dataPostYear = "{viewType:'"+ GetViewType() + "',viewDate:'2009/09/08',languageId:'"+GetLanguageId()+"}";

 $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: url,
   data: dataPostYear,
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   dataType: "json",
   success: OnLoadYearListSuccess,
   error: OnLoadYearListError  
  });
```

GetViewType() return --'0'
languageId()  return --'1'

it's just a string

there is a way to post an object, something what I try to do in my first way ? Or not ?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean, it doesn't work? The first version will work fine, that's how the data parameter is *supposed* to work. Is the error client or server side? How are you decoding the data server-side?

Comment: I assume the second works because it's just a string. it's very invalid with unmatched single quotes, no double quoted parameters. The first should work fine.

Comment: can you post GetViewType and GetLangaugeId methods?

Answer (score 0):

Use `jQuery.param()`. Here is the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/)

Comment: Then there is something else you are not telling us. That code should be exactly what you are looking for: **jQuery.param()**: _Create a serialized representation of an array or object, suitable for use in a URL query string or Ajax request._

Answer (score 0):

You should look at [.postJSON](http://abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/05/postjson-for-jquery/).

Essentially, you just add json as a 4th argument to the $.post

From the site:

```
// Send the request
$.post('script.php', data, function(response) {
// Do something with the request
}, 'json');
```

If you want the .ajax call version, you can convert it using the [.post docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/).